# PHPWord how to add text break / new line while in a text run

Tags: php, format, line, phpword

How can I add a text break or go to the next line/row while in a text run? I tried to just do `$section->addTextBreak(2);` while in the text run but it just added the breaks to the section after the text run. I also tried `$textrun->addTextBreak(2);` but it gave me a fatal error. Any responses would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm afraid that this will not be possible with current version. I don't have deep understanding of this library, but from looking at the code, I found out that the `textRun` class consist only of `addText` and `addLink` methods.

But I also need this feature along with several others, so I'm going to write it myself and create a pull request to get it included in the next release (if there will be any).

Basically it can be done by modifying the `textRun` class, adding an `addLineBreak` method (similar way as it is in the section class) and then modify class `Base.php` to create proper elements in final document.

In Docx xml, those line brakes are similar to the html `br` tag, but previous text must be closed and reopened after using break like this:

```
<w:r>
  <w:t>This is</w:t>
  <w:br/>
  <w:t xml:space="preserve"> a simple sentence.</w:t>
</w:r>
```

instead of simply doing

```
<w:r>
  <w:t>This is<w:br /> a simple sentence</w:t>
</w:r>
```

So in `base.php`, you'll need to edit behavior to create this block of code.

Hope this was useful!

EDIT

I have figured out that implementing this is very simple. In `textRun.php` just add this method:

```
/**
* Add a TextBreak Element
*
* @param int $count
*/
public function addTextBreak($count = 1) {
    for($i=1; $i<=$count; $i++) {
        $this->_elementCollection[] = new PHPWord_Section_TextBreak();
    }
}
```

and in `Base.php` in the `_writeTextRun` method at the end of this method add this condition:

```
elseif($element instanceof PHPWord_Section_TextBreak) {
    $objWriter->writeElement('w:br');
}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused exactly where I put the code in Base.php. At the end of which curly bracket? There are 2 if tests at the very end. Also how would you add the break in after adding this code to the library?

Comment: Oh never mind I got it working. Thanks for the help, you have no clue how much time you have saved me!

Comment: Since you seem to be really knowagable about this could you look at this question and see if you could provide any help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757477/phpword-xml-indent-a-line ? Thanks!

Comment: @user2579723 sorry for late response, the question you linked is deleted now :(

Comment: wait where in the method do you put it?  the br isnt writng into the xml file from within the word file when unzipped manually.  before the last curly curly brace that ends the function?  Or after the other elseif from within the same if block inside the foreach which seems to make sense since other methods are there too?  Or not since it is an element?  Can you post the _writeTextRun function that does it please?

Comment: @user2579723 - i dont know if saying your name will trigger a response from three years but can you tell where you put the elseif no matter where i put it, it doesnt work.

Comment: to use this with TemplateProcessor just add '</w:t><w:br/><w:t xml:space="preserve">' (instead of <w:br />) between parts of row you want to separate by new line.
Like this:
$templateProcessor->setValue('test', 'TEST</w:t><w:br/><w:t xml:space="preserve">TEST</w:t><w:br/><w:t xml:space="preserve">TEST');

Answer (score 20):

The question was asked 3 years ago but I have the same problem and I found a solution. Maybe this can help new users of `PHPWord`.

To add a crlf in Word document the tag `<w:br/>` can help :

```
$section->addText('Some text <w:br/> another text in the line ');
```

I found the solution here : http://jeroen.is/phpword-line-breaks/

Comment: This requires `\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setOutputEscapingEnabled(false);` and XML-escaping all of the text yourself.

Comment: Note that this solution also works when using setValue for the TemplateProcessor:

`$templateProcessor->setValue('contact_address', '1st Line<w:br />2nd Line');`

Comment: For me it worked out of the box with PhpWord 1.0. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks @Jake! That did the trick for me!

Comment: @Jared getting error - `Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Namespace prefix w on br is not defined in Entity`.

Comment: @Jared How can we use `<w:br/>` in a `table`? Kindly suggest.

Comment: Not worked for me. `$table->addCell(3000)->addText('Hello Friends-3<w:br/>I am fine-3', $TfontStyle, array('align' => 'left', 'spaceAfter' => 0) );`

Answer (score 8):

Try this one:

```
    str_replace("\n", '</w:t><w:br/><w:t xml:space="preserve">', $yourData );
```

or this one

```
    str_replace("\r\n", '</w:t><w:br/><w:t xml:space="preserve">', $yourData );
```

Comment: @gaelle3182's solution didn't work for me when doing a string replace for the TemplateProcessor but this did, cheers

Answer (score 6):

You can have a text and add `\n` where ever you want to have line breaks, and do the rest like this:

```
$text = "foo\nbar\nfoobar";
$textlines = explode("\n", $text);

$textrun = $section->addTextRun();
$textrun->addText(array_shift($textlines));

foreach($textlines as $line) {
    $textrun->addTextBreak();
    // maybe twice if you want to seperate the text
    // $textrun->addTextBreak(2);
    $textrun->addText($line);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding a newline in phpword has bothered me, and I finnaly found solution, by accident, so here it is:
And this justifies the text.

```
$PHPWord->addParagraphStyle('pJustify', array('align' => 'both', 'spaceBefore' => 0, 'spaceAfter' => 0, 'spacing' => 0));
//add this style then append it to text below
$section->addText('something', 'textstyle', 'pJustify');
//the text behind this will be justified and will be in a new line, not in a new paragraph
$section->addText('behind', 'textstyle', 'pJustify');
```

This will output:

something

behind

Comment: This creates two paragraphs with the spacing between them set to zero.  It does not create one paragraph with a line break within it.

Comment: How will it work when we have a table cell and have to write texts in 3 lines?

Answer (score 2):

It's easy: just start a new textrun, and before it add textbreak to the section, like this (tested with docx format):

```
$textrun = $section->addTextRun();

$textrun->addText('blah-blah', 'p_bold');

  $section->addTextBreak(2);

  $textrun = $section->addTextRun();

  $textrun->addText('blah-blah-blah in new line ', 'p');

  $textrun->addText('blah-blah', 'p_bold');

  $textrun->addText('blah-blah', 'p');

  $section->addTextBreak(2);

  $textrun = $section->addTextRun();

  $textrun->addText('blahblah', 'p');
```

Comment: also helpful: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/958#issuecomment-318913636

Comment: This does not create any paragraphs with line breaks within them.  It creates several paragraphs, some of which are empty.

Answer (score 1):

For correct work, you need to add a text block:

```
$string = strtr($string, [
   "\n" => "</w:t>\n<w:br />\n<w:t xml:space=\"preserve\">"
]);
```

Comment: This requires `\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setOutputEscapingEnabled(false);` and XML-escaping all of the text yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if a PR from the accepted answer was incorporated or it was in fact already possible in 2013, but regardless, since 2015 if not earlier, the correct way to insert line breaks within a paragraph is indicated in the [initial response to #553 on GitHub](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/553#issuecomment-112743470):

- Create a `TextRun` for the paragraph;
- Add line breaks to the
  `TextRun` by calling the `addTextBreak()` method ***of the `TextRun`
  itself***.

Here's a function that will take care of this for a complete paragraph of text in a string containing literal line-breaks (CR-LF [`"\r\n"`], LF [`"\n"`] or CR [`"\r"`]):

```
/**
 * @param \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\AbstractContainer $container
 *        E.g. a section or table cell.
 * @param string $text String with literal line breaks as CR-LF, LF or CR.
 * @param string|array|\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Paragraph $paragraphStyle
 * @param string|array|\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Font $fontStyle
 *
 * @return \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\TextRun
 */
function addTextWithLineBreaks(
  \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\AbstractContainer $container,
  $text,
  $fontStyle,
  $paragraphStyle
) {
  $textRun = $container->addTextRun($paragraphStyle);
  foreach (preg_split('/(\\r\\n?+|\\n)/',
    $text,
    -1,
    PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE
  ) as $i => $part) {
    if ($i & 1) {
      $textRun->addTextBreak(1, $fontStyle, $paragraphStyle);
    } else {
      $textRun->addText($part, $fontStyle, $paragraphStyle);
    }
  }
  return $textRun;
}
```

PHPWord (0.14.0) currently discards line breaks when reading Word2007 documents – hopefully that will be fixed before 1.0 – but the output from the above is correct when opened in Word.

Comment: Not fixed this issue in 1.0 version, still facing this issue

Comment: Lots of programmers seem to have no clue as to where and when they should do escaping and unescaping.  Simple answer: point of source; point of destination; and only ever then.  WordPress is riddled with bugs due to double-escaping because the wrong fixes have been applied.  The developers of this library don't seem to understand the issue either.

Answer (score 0):

use PHP_EOL for line break it is the only solution for line break in PHPWord

Answer (score 0):

I have tried ALL the posted decisions on github, stackoverflow, different sites, I was googling for 3 days and nothing worked. So I went to the docx document, renamed its extension to the zip, and checked the document xml schema.

So there is a bit of code, that can be used for inserting a new line without text break bug:

```php
<?php
$textRun = new TextRun();
$textRun>addText('A long text here');

// new line
$textRun->addText('</w:t></w:r></w:p>
    <w:p>
      <w:pPr>
      <w:contextualSpacing/>
        <w:jc w:val="both"/>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman"/>
        </w:rPr>
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
      <w:t>');

// a second row
$textRun>addText('Another long text here');

// replace a variable
$doc->setComplexValue('Variable', $textRun);
```

In my case I'm using Times New Roman, and justify text alignment. You can set your own options for the paragraph, but you should specify them in ooxml format using tags. Hope this helps somebody