# using phpword to download an attachment word file

Tags: php, html, download, ms-word, phpword

my problem is I want to be able to download the text area content as word file 
-the code is work if I stop at saving to server code (the content are exactly as written in the text area)
-but when I added the download code the downloaded file will contain the programed page format
please help me

the used code is:

```
// Create a new PHPWord Object
$PHPWord = new PHPWord();

$section = $PHPWord->createSection();

$section->addText($_POST['editor1']); //textarea content

$objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');
//$objWriter->save('helloWorld.docx');
$temp_file_uri = tempnam('', 'xyz');
$objWriter->save($temp_file_uri);
//download code
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=helloWorld.docx');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($temp_file_uri));
readfile($temp_file_uri);
unlink($temp_file_uri); // deletes the temporary file
exit;

}?>
```

**Update:**
I found what the problem was that was only because I don't have office 2007 
sorry but the file was open as word file even if I wasn't have office so I thought that will not be the problem maker :( sorry for bothering you

but still there is problems before opening the file I receive warning message "said that the content are corrupted and if I'm not ensure from the source I shoudn't open it!"
also there is no breaks between lines (as if I wrote all words in one paragraph!

Answer (score 0):

for linebreaks I found useful code written be @j0hny "thanks johny :)"
[linebreaks code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17689188/phpword-how-to-add-text-break-new-line-while-in-a-text-run)

and for the error message it was dissappear when I used "HTML to docx Converter" which incloud phpword you can find it here [here](https://htmltodocx.codeplex.com/)